# Send int and String as param in volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Am trying to send String and int as params in volley. But it show error on String if i use `Map<String,Integer> params = new HashMap<String, String>();` and show error on int if i use `Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();` So how can i send int and String as a param in post request.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.aaa.com/insert/signup" ,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("sign_up_res", response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error" , error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("firstname" , PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString(Local_Preference.FIRSTNAME, "Not Set") );
            params.put("number" , "123");
            return params;
        }
    };
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    1000,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUp2Activity.this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

In Sql table is like `firstname (varchar)` and `number(int)`. I don't want to change the int type to varchar in sql. Is there any way to send `int` and `String` in a single params.

Comment: Store int as String after reading from DB

Comment: But i am taking these fields from the user, so how can i send these two in the above format ?

Answer (score 4):

you can do this create a

> Map params = new HashMap();

then

```
params.put(key,value); // for string 
params.put(key,String.valueOf(value)); // for int As suggested
```

Comment: Good to use `String.valueOf` instead of ""

Comment: thank Dear that the correct way to use what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the code using this my problem is solved

```
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json";

ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();     

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "Androidhive");
                params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
                params.put("password", "password123");



                return params;
            }

        };

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

Comment: Or you can add headers also if you problem is not solved
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("apiKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

Comment: if my solution is best for you then please accept my answer

Comment: I want to send int instead of String

Comment: You can change key is string and value is int simple

Comment: This answer is wrong, clearly the OP is asking how to send int as value in params using Volley, whereas you have simply written the code for String.